# What is the best way to handle notification creation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I have a notification model which has a type, user id and model id, that are displayed in the users feed, at the moment I have a load of methods in the user model that create instances of notification model and store them in the database, I think it's not a good idea to put them there and I have thought about making a controller that creates the notifications, is that the best way or is it better to create a helper function to do it?